# JPA creating table

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have trouble with MySql and JPA and I try to configure JPA with db. To create tables.

Connectin stuck on creation entity manager factory

```
  EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory =     Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("JPAService");
    EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();

    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();

    UserRole user = new UserRole("USER");
    UserRole admin = new UserRole("ADMIN");
    entityManager.persist(user);
    entityManager.persist(admin);
    User p1 = new User(user, "Pawel", "Brzeczyszczykiewicz", "sdf 17/2", "Krakow", "gty@interia.pl");
    User p2 = new User(admin, "Admin", "Adminowo", "Warszawa", "War", "");
    User p3 = new User(user, "Bogdan", "Łazuka", "Brzeg  12", "Warszawa", "blazuka@op.eu");
    entityManager.persist(p1);
    entityManager.persist(p2);
    entityManager.persist(p3);

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
    entityManagerFactory.close();
```

There is my persistance.xml

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence" version="1.0">
  <persistence-unit name="JPAService" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <properties>

       <!-- Configuring JDBC properties -->
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:8080//shop" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="root" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="" />
      <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />

      <!-- Hibernate properties -->
      <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true" />
      <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="MySQL5InnoDBDialect" />
      <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="create" />     


      <!-- Configuring Connection Pool -->
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.min_size" value="5" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_size" value="20" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.timeout" value="500" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.max_statements" value="50" />
      <property name="hibernate.c3p0.idle_test_period" value="2000" />
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

I don't know what could be the reason becouse nothing failed hear and there is no log

Comment: I doubt your musql database listens on port 8080. Your URL is wrong. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

Comment: Thank you so much it resolve the problem. There was one another issue with dialect value becouse it should be org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect

Comment: `<property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect" />` might help you.